# Does `cat -v` provide adequate protection against control character injection and other similar attacks?

Tags: terminal

I need to `cat` an untrusted file on a remote server. I'm doing this by logging in with SSH.

There are known risks related to `cat`-ing untrusted files. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56307).

The `cat -v` option can be used to encode non-printing characters:

```
-v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

Does this `-v` option provide adequate protection against control character injection and other attacks?

There is also the `-E` option, which shows a `$` at the end of lines. Is there a security benefit to using `-E` too?

If I were to `cat` a maliciously crafted file with an exploit, which system would actually be compromised? The remote server where the file is located and the `cat` command is running, or the local machine with the SSH client that is actually displaying the data?

Comment: You would exploit the local machine, assuming the exploit was compatible with it.

Comment: @LSerni Assuming it's a PTY over SSH and not, say, X11 forwarding of a vulnreable xterm.

Comment: @LSerni So you mean the client machine displaying the output would be compromised, rather than the remote server where ```cat``` is running and the file is located?

Comment: @rubberband876 Yes, taking into account forest's proviso. What "powers" the compromise is the output being interpreted, so it happens wherever the output, indeed, gets interpreted; not where it is generated by `cat` or otherwise, nor where the final graphical result is displayed.